# Send emails with SMTP protocol using socket class - Java

Tags: java, sockets, smtp

I'm trying to develop a class that sends email using the SMTP protocol, without using any libraries that facilitate sending mail, such as MimeMessage or MailUtility.

This is what I've done so far:

```
public class MailSender {

    protected String localMachine;
    protected String localSMTPServer;
    private String textMail;

    private String mailFrom;

    public MailSender(String localSMTPServer, String mailFrom) {
        try {
            this.textMail = "null";
            this.localSMTPServer = localSMTPServer;
            this.mailFrom = mailFrom;

            InetAddress localIP = InetAddress.getLocalHost();
            this.localMachine = localIP.getHostAddress();

        } catch (UnknownHostException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(MailSender.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }

    //getter and setter
    public void smtp(String command) {
        try {
            System.out.println(sIn.readLine());
            os.write((command + "\n").getBytes());
            System.out.println("end");
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            System.out.println(ex);
            Logger.getLogger(MailSender.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }           
    }

    BufferedReader sIn;
    OutputStream os;

    public Boolean trySend(String destUser, String subject, String message) {
        Socket socket;
        try {
            socket = new Socket(localSMTPServer, 587);

            OutputStreamWriter sOutW = new OutputStreamWriter(socket.getOutputStream(), "ASCII");

            PrintWriter sOut = new PrintWriter(sOutW, true);
            InputStreamReader sInR = new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream(), "ASCII");
            
            sIn = new BufferedReader(sInR);
            os = socket.getOutputStream();
            this.nextSMTPCode(sIn, 220);
            sOut.println("EHLO");
            this.nextSMTPCode(sIn, 250);
      
            sOut.println("AUTH LOGIN");
            this.nextSMTPCode(sIn, 250);
            
            sOut.println("xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx=="); //username 
            sOut.println("xxxxxxxxxxxxxx="); //password 
            this.nextSMTPCode(sIn, 250);
            
            sOut.println("MAIL FROM: <" + this.mailFrom + ">");
            this.nextSMTPCode(sIn, 250);
            sOut.println("RCPT TO: <" + destUser + ">");
            this.nextSMTPCode(sIn, 250);
            
            sOut.println("DATA");
            this.nextSMTPCode(sIn, 250);
            sOut.println("From: " + this.mailFrom);
            sOut.println("To: " + destUser);
            sOut.println("Subject: " + subject);
            sOut.println(message);
            
            sOut.println(".");
            this.nextSMTPCode(sIn, 250);
            
            sOut.println("QUIT");
            this.nextSMTPCode(sIn, 250);
            
            sIn.close();
            textMail = "From " + this.mailFrom + " To " + destUser + "\n" + "Subject: " + subject + "\nMessage: " + message;
            return true;
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(MailSender.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }

        return false;
    }

    public String getMail() {
        return textMail;
    }

    private void nextSMTPCode(BufferedReader sIn, int expectedCode) throws IOException {    
        int code;
        String str = sIn.readLine();
        System.out.println(str);
        String sCode = str.substring(0, 3);
        code = Integer.parseInt(sCode);

        if (code != expectedCode) {    
            sIn.close();
            System.out.println("Code: " + code + " expected code was: " + expectedCode);
            throw new IOException();
        }
    }
}
```

I am having problem with communication with the SMTP server (I am using smtp2go as the server).

**The problem is that I keep getting the 250 code even when this shouldn't show up**, finally the email isn't sent.

This is a sample communication:

```
220 mail.smtp2go.com ESMTP Exim 4.96-S2G Tue, 10 Jan 2023 14:42:02+0000
250-mail.smtp2go.com Hello  [xxxxx] 
250-SIZE 52428800 
250-8BITMIME 
250-DSN
250-PIPELINING 
250-PIPECONNECT 
250-AUTH CRAM-MD5 PLAIN LOGIN 
250-CHUNKING
```

**I then get 250-SIZE 52428800 and the other responses (always with the code 250) for every command I send**. I tried to telnet and everything seems to work, the problem is in my code, but I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong.

Does anyone know the cause of this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SMTP can have multiline responses, but you only expect singleline responses. Multiline responses are typical for EHLO. To cite from [RFC 5231](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5321#section-4.2.1):

> The format for multiline replies requires that every line, except the last, begin with the reply code, followed immediately by a hyphen, "-" (also known as minus), followed by text.  The last line will begin with the reply code, followed immediately by <SP>, optionally some text, and <CRLF>.  As noted above, servers SHOULD send the <SP> if subsequent text is not sent, but clients MUST be prepared for it to be omitted.
>
> For example:
>
> ```
>  250-First line
>  250-Second line
>  250-234 Text beginning with numbers
>  250 The last line
> ```